# Xcode 6: display called functions in real time

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I'm building a simple iOS app to retrieve some json data and display annotations in a MKMapView.

I get freezes at launch and I'd like to debug it and I was wondering if it's possible to see in real time what functions are called on device with Xcode in order to see where hangs occur.

Comment: just add logging statements all over the place and see what gets called when and which statements take long to exectue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hit pause in Xcode's debugger, and if your main thread is blocked, it should show you a meaningful stack trace.

Comment: That seems quite useful but stack trace isn't very meaningful to me, how do I know what these threads and processes do?

Comment: @Skoua Ideally one of these threads should be running a method you recognize, if you suspect your code is what's causing the problem. Thread 0 is the main thread. Generally if the main thread is stuck running something for a long time, it won't react to input, and hence _hang_.

Comment: Yup got that. Thread 1 (there's no 0 in my debug view) is indeed very high at start, CPU goes up to 150% and then goes down to about 10%. Should I look at mach_msg_trap or UIApplicationMain?

Comment: @Skoua Ah, if you're seeing that means something else is wrong. Try using time profiling in Instruments, that might help you.

Comment: Ok found it! I'm looping through this big JSON array and that's what's creating hangs. I need to find a way to make it faster now.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: add `NSLog` to your methods and look at the timestamps. You can add one at the top of your method and one at the bottom to see how long that method takes to execute.

More advanced and powerful: Time Profiling in Instruments. [How to Use Instruments in Xcode](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode)